# Query to retrieve stock quotes variation from a single day

Tags: rest, yql, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I'm quite new YQL and i've found the query to retrieve a single quote from a stock

`select * from yahoo.finance.quote symbol = "YHOO"`

and another query to get this same information but on date range

`select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2016-09-01" and endDate = "2016-09-22"`

What i could not figure out was: **how could we retrieve quotes from a full day of trading?**

I'm currently using the Yahoo finance app and notice they provide a good graphic about the price variation, so i presume there is a way to achieve it.

*I also tried to read [yql tables](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.historicaldata.xml) repository but on both table that i am using there is no (at least explicit) clue of how to pass hour range.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the complete quotes of a day by querying the Yahoo Finance API endpoint directly (not via YQL) and receiving a list in JSON format.

The end point is  `http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/$symbol/chartdata;type=$type;range=$range/json/`, where:

- `$symbol` is the stock ticker symbol, e.g. `AAPL` for Apple or `BAS.DE` for BASF traded at Xetra
- `$type` is the type of the query, you can query for `quote`, `sma`, `close`, `volume`
- `$range` is the desired latest days with `1d`,  `5d`, `10d`, `15d`

An example query would be
`http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/aapl/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/json/`
which gives you all quotes from `AAPL` from the last day.

As far as I know, you can only query for the quotes up to the last 15 days. I have not yet found a way to query for some other day further in the past.

Just my self-centric hint: check out my PHP package [YahooFinanceQuery on Github](https://github.com/dirkolbrich/yahoo-finance-query), which uses an implementation of the above query and handles the returning JSON to filter the results.

Comment: I tried to query the 5D and notice that the query is actually cumulative. So there is no way to get by exactly date, right?

Comment: Sorry, nope. Not possibe as far as I know. Only the daily quotes of the last 15 days.

Comment: The sample query for Apple stock doesn't work. Chrome reports no server found for chartapi.finance.yahoo.com

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Yahoo changed their API endpoints in early 2017.

Comment: I found another API endpoint, which seems to allow to download daily quotes - `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/DBK.DE?range=1d&includePrePost=false&interval=2m&corsDomain=de.finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance`. It just gives OHLCV information, but the intervals and granularity are changeable. Just start playing with the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

As an update/extension to my previous answer I found a new API endpoint to download daily quotes.
Yahoo changed their API endpoints in early 2017.

The new endpoint is:
`https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{$symbol}?range={$range}&interval={$interval}`, where:

- $symbol is the stock ticker symbol, e.g. AAPL for Apple
- $range is the desired range of the query, allowed parameters are [1d, 5d, 1mo, 3mo, 6mo, 1y, 2y, 5y, 10y, ytd, max]
- $interval is the desired interval of the quote, e.g. every 5 minutes, allowed parameters are [1m, 2m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 60m, 90m, 1h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo]

An example would be: `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?range=10d&interval=1m` where you receive OHLCV quotes for the AAPL stock from the last 10 trading days with a 1 minute interval. All in a nicely JSON format.

Not all $range parameters will return results with the specified $interval, but will return the nearest possible combination. For example, the "max" range will return all quotes with a "1mo" interval.

Comment: I just saw now. Will try it in a bit